# JMX or NetMX real-world examples

Tags: .net, monitoring, jmx

I'm currently researching NetMX (and JMX by association) for a systems monitoring project.  Does anyone have any real world examples of either of these libraries?
The only examples I can find are manipulating a counter via JConsole which isn't helping me get a bigger picture.

Thanks for any help...

Jon

Comment: What kind of uses are you looking for in particular?

Comment: I'm really broad scoped right now and that may be part of the problem...But I would like a little bit of everything:
-remote runtime changes of objects, config params, etc...
-performance stats...
-health monitoring...
-other capabilities I don't know about...

It seems like a combination of JMX with AOP can somehow get me all these things.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of NETMX so I can't help you there.

But there's a configuration service that Microsoft built into the StockTrader demonstration application, that shows how you might do distributed monitoring or even configuration for distributed apps.  It does read-write of configuration settings, much like JMX I think.

Go to [the StockTrader page on Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684.aspx) and search down for  "Configuration Service".  There's [full source code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/6/486b4b4f-5a87-4b5c-beec-455290f83274/StockTraderSetup.msi), and [a technical guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/8/6/486b4b4f-5a87-4b5c-beec-455290f83274/ConfigServiceTechnicalGuide.pdf) (PDF) available.

The configuration service is implemented as boilerplate WCF code that you include into your application.  Because it uses web services, the systems you are configuring do not have to be running on the same server.  It's a nice flexible way to read or update application configuration settings for a distributed server-based .NET application.  There's support for clones - stateless apps that all do the same thing, as you might have for a large scale service.  Under this service, all clones get the same configuration metadata. Bunch of other neat pieces. check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the configuration service, I had never heard of that.  The service seems like it wants to do A LOT:
-Centralized configuration manager
-App-level failover
-Distributed caching!??!?!
-Health monitoring

I need to do some reading. Thanks again.